# want to pass ng-repeat object to custom filter function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Aim:**

A user should be able to type into the search field the name of a course, and see a list of students who are registered on that course.

**Models:**

```
course (has a course name and course code)
student (has a list of registered courses)
students (an array of student objects)
```

**Method:**

ng-repeat through a list of student objects. For each student object, pass object to a custom filter function `filterByCourse(byCourse, student)`.

*To be implemented:* filterByCourse function iterates through student.courses. If a course with the same name or code as byCourse is found, this is added to a list of filteredStudents. pass the filteredStudents list to the view in place of the unfiltered list of students.

**Here's the code:**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="byCourse"
placeholder="Search by course id or course name..">

<ul ng-repeat="student in students | filter: filterByCourse(byCourse, student)">
        <li ng-init="index=0; classes=['list--students_item', 'list--students_item--active']" ng-click="stageMeToCourse($index)" 
            ng-class="classes[index % classes.length]" 
            class="col-xs-24">

            <img src="/img/profile_default.png">
            <h4>{{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }} 
                <span class="role">{{ student.role }}</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </h4>
            <p class="student_nr">{{ student._id }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!--list-students-->
```

**The Problem:**

When I pass the student object into filterByCourse, a console.log on the first line shows that student is undefined, so I can't iterate through the courses and return a list of filtered students as I'd like to.

```
scope.filterByCourse = function(course, student){
    console.log(student); //student is undefined
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

- I've tried to use the filter function in the ng-repeat to iterate through each student object's course list but cannot figure out how to do it.
- I've tried hitting things with hammers.

**Further problem:**

I only wish to filter the results in this way if the user has entered some string into the input field. If the input field is empty the filter function should not be triggered. I have no idea how to do this bit!

Comment: Please show your filter function, since we won't be able to see what's wrong without your showing how you've implemented it. Maybe it's better anyway to create a custom filter, instead of calling a function with the built in Angular filter function.

Comment: @pkeuter the custom filter function is not implemented yet. All it does so far is console.log student which is undefined when the function is called from the veiw. That's the first problem :/

Comment: I understand that it's not fully implemented yet, but you started to implement it and are getting an error message in that function. Please show it so we can see what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @JulianBlair please see updated answer with option2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**:

What you are trying to create is called a predicate function. You can read up on it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)(just scroll to `function(value, index, array)`)

> A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.
>
> The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for

Please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/wdLkztyj/2/)

If you type in "course" you will see both students, if you type "course1" you will only see the first student. The same counts for the course code "CC1"

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController" class="panel panel-primary">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="studentFilter">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="panel-heading">Students</div>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:onFilterStudents">
      {{student.firstName}} {{student.surname}}
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="course in student.courses">
            {{course.courseName}}-{{course.courseCode}}
          </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.students = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe',
    courses: [{
      courseName: 'course1',
      courseCode: 'CC1'
    }, {
      courseName: 'course2',
      courseCode: 'CC7'
    }]
  }, {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    surname: 'Doe',
    courses: [{
      courseName: 'course3',
      courseCode: 'CC2'
    }, {
      courseName: 'course4',
      courseCode: 'CC3'
    }]
  }];

  $scope.onFilterStudents = function(value, index, array) {
    if ($scope.studentFilter === '' || $scope.studentFilter === null || $scope.studentFilter === undefined) {
      return true;
    }    
    return value.courses.filter(function(course) {
    console.log(course);
      return course.courseName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.studentFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1 || course.courseCode.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.studentFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }).length > 0;
  };
}]);
```

**Option 2**

You can use a object as the [filter expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)(scroll to Object: A pattern ob...), please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wdLkztyj/4/)

> A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its nested object properties. That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !. For example {name: "!M"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name not containing "M".

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController" class="panel panel-primary">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="studentFilter">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="panel-heading">Students</div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:{courses:{$:studentFilter}}">
      {{student.firstName}} {{student.surname}}
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="course in student.courses">
          {{course.courseName}}-{{course.courseCode}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.students = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe',
    courses: [{
      courseName: 'course1',
      courseCode: 'CC1'
    }, {
      courseName: 'course2',
      courseCode: 'CC7'
    }]
  }, {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    surname: 'Doe',
    courses: [{
      courseName: 'course3',
      courseCode: 'CC2'
    }, {
      courseName: 'course4',
      courseCode: 'CC3'
    }]
  }];  
}]);
```

If no custom code or advanced filtering is required, I opt for option 2

Comment: This worked wonderfully!

One question - does the last line .length > 0 function as a kind of conditional? So it only returns if the length is greater than 0?

Great answer!

Comment: `.length` returns the length of the filtered courses for the current student in the iteration, we only want to see students where the they have a matching courses listed and this is why we return `.length>0`

Comment: I know what the length property is for but I'm asking if  "length > 0;" is like a conditional that returns true if the length is greater than 0 and false if it is not greater than 0? Pretty sure that's what's going on ..

Answer (score 4):

The function

```
filterByCourse
```

should be called only with 'byCourse' in the html, and it's implementation should only receive the parameter 'byCourse'. This function also should **return a function** that receives a student object.
so you're html should be

```
<ul ng-repeat="student in students | filter: filterByCourse(byCourse)">
```

and in the javascript it should be

```
$scope.filterByCourse = function (byCourse) {
  return function (student) {
      console.log(student);
  }
};
```

(the function that the filter returns would have access to the byCourse parameter cuz its in the same context).
here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp384kx2/)